# Kubernetes hostPath volume always freezes pod

Tags: kubernetes, minikube, volumes

I have this pod definition file using the basic nginx container image.  All I am doing in this POD is to attempt to mount a local directory so that it can be accessed by the pod.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
   name: empty-pod
   labels:
      name: empty-pod
spec:
  containers:
  - name: empty
    image: nginx
    ports: 
      - containerPort: 80
    volumeMounts:
      - name: db-persistence
        mountPath: /data/db
  volumes:
    - name: db-persistence
      hostPath:
        path: /c/MongoData/
        type: Directory
```

I have two different minikube environments, both Windows machines, one using Docker Desktop and the other VirtualBox.  Using the definition above, and attempt to create the pod gives a pod that never actually starts:

```
d:\Kubernetes\exercise>kubectl get all
NAME            READY   STATUS              RESTARTS   AGE
pod/empty-pod   0/1     ContainerCreating   0          8m30s

NAME                 TYPE        CLUSTER-IP   EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)   AGE
service/kubernetes   ClusterIP   10.96.0.1    <none>        443/TCP   7d7h
```

The folder it is mounting is empty at this point.  I have also tried with files in there.  It just seems to freeze up.   Deleting the pod takes a long time (several minutes) as well.  As far as I can tell, this is the textbook example of how to mount a file system from the host into the pod/container.  Any idea what I am doing wrong?

UPDATE: describe on the pod gives:

```
Name:         empty-pod
Namespace:    default
Priority:     0
Node:         minikube/192.168.59.100
Start Time:   Mon, 10 Jan 2022 21:49:37 -0800
Labels:       app=photegrity
              name=empty-pod
Annotations:  <none>
Status:       Pending
IP:
IPs:          <none>
Containers:
  empty:
    Container ID:
    Image:          nginx
    Image ID:
    Port:           80/TCP
    Host Port:      0/TCP
    State:          Waiting
      Reason:       ContainerCreating
    Ready:          False
    Restart Count:  0
    Environment:    <none>
    Mounts:
      /data/db from mongodb-persistence (rw)
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from kube-api-access-6xwsc (ro)
Conditions:
  Type              Status
  Initialized       True
  Ready             False
  ContainersReady   False
  PodScheduled      True
Volumes:
  mongodb-persistence:
    Type:          HostPath (bare host directory volume)
    Path:          /c/MongoData/
    HostPathType:  Directory
  kube-api-access-6xwsc:
    Type:                    Projected (a volume that contains injected data from multiple sources)
    TokenExpirationSeconds:  3607
    ConfigMapName:           kube-root-ca.crt
    ConfigMapOptional:       <nil>
    DownwardAPI:             true
QoS Class:                   BestEffort
Node-Selectors:              <none>
Tolerations:                 node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
                             node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
Events:
  Type     Reason       Age                   From               Message
  ----     ------       ----                  ----               -------
  Normal   Scheduled    44m                   default-scheduler  Successfully assigned default/empty-pod to minikube
  Warning  FailedMount  41m                   kubelet            Unable to attach or mount volumes: unmounted volumes=[mongodb-persistence], unattached volumes=[kube-api-access-6xwsc mongodb-persistence]: timed out waiting for the condition
  Warning  FailedMount  13m (x23 over 44m)    kubelet            MountVolume.SetUp failed for volume "mongodb-persistence" : hostPath type check failed: /c/MongoData/ is not a directory
  Warning  FailedMount  3m29s (x15 over 39m)  kubelet            Unable to attach or mount volumes: unmounted volumes=[mongodb-persistence], unattached volumes=[mongodb-persistence kube-api-access-6xwsc]: timed out waiting for the condition
```

This is a windows path `C:\MongoData` and in Docker I have used the unixized path `/c/MongoData` but any idea what Kubernetes would like to call this path?

Comment: Can you use `kubectl describe po empty-pod` to provide more information?

Answer (score 0):

This is one place where I have spent a lot of time and finally figured out the way to mount windows based paths on pods in Kubernetes.

If you are using a Windows system, you need to prefix '/run/desktop/mnt/host/' to the value in `path` attribute. So the YAML would look something like this:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
   name: empty-pod
   labels:
      name: empty-pod
spec:
  containers:
  - name: empty
    image: nginx
    ports: 
      - containerPort: 80
    volumeMounts:
      - name: db-persistence
        mountPath: /data/db
  volumes:
    - name: db-persistence
      hostPath:
        path: /run/desktop/mnt/host/c/MongoData/
        type: Directory
```

Honestly, I feel this should have been a part of the documentation but somehow it is not.

Comment: Still fails to start, FailedMount.   Now I get:  MountVolume.SetUp failed for volume "db-persistence" : hostPath type check failed: /run/desktop/mnt/host/c/MongoData/ is not a directory

Comment: Does this Directory exist yet? If not you can create that directory first manually, or you may try to change the type as `type: DirectoryorCreate` for Kubernetes to automatically create that directory for you if it does not already exist.

Comment: With `DirectoryOrCreate` I was able to get it to start, but it is an empty directory and clearly not mapped to the windows folder.  I created something inside the mount point, and nothing appeared outside, and creating a file outside is not seen inside either.   This is on the VirtualBox miniKube.   Same behavior with the DockerDesktop miniKube.

Comment: MiniKube is running as a Docker container, and I can find the modified file in there.   But not on my Windows machine.   I might need to do something else to make this windows file system available to the kubernetes cluster.   What a bother.  I was able to do this with Docker.

Comment: you can use 'minikube mount' to mount directory into minikube container

Comment: @AgilePro if the answer was able to resolve your original issue, kindly consider accepting and upvoting the answer